# Can't use the BER TLV library (JavaCard) in Java SE application?

Tags: java, javacard, tlv

I have imported all the necessary tlv libraries (library for JavaCard) to the Java SE application, but it does not work as expected.

Example, in the JavaCard applet, when I try to run:

```
byte data[] = {(byte) 0xc1, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x02};

if (BERTLV.verifyFormat(data, (short) 0, (short) 4)) {

        ISOException.throwIt((short) 0x6666);

}
```

The status word I received is 0x6666. That is, data is a well-formed BER TLV representation.

But, when I try to run the Java SE code:

```
byte data[] = {(byte) 0xc1, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x02};

System.out.println(BERTLV.verifyFormat(data, (short) 0, (short) 4));
```

The result is false. That is, data is not a well-formed BER TLV representation.

Similarly, some other functions do not work correctly in the Java SE application.

How can I fix it?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: How did you import the libraries? Did you have access to specific class files, or did you try and implement the API? In general there is little need to import them; instead you could use the BER facilities in, for instance, Bouncy Castle. The TLV libraries of Java Card are constrained because of the lack of integer support and  GC features.

Comment: Thank you for recommending me. I will try to use Bouncy Castle. Just as, no errors when compiled and run the source code, but but the results were not correct, so I feel very strange.

Comment: I've tested a few libs on SE before migrating them to Java Card, so without the source I can only agree that it is strange. It could still have something to do with `int` missing, but it would have to be a corner case that goes wrong. It should not be hard to replicate the API yourself on Java SE but don't forget to test well, I've seen oodles of libraries getting it wrong.

Comment: I will try to do what you recommend. Again, thank you for your help.

Comment: I have taken a look at the API and I've concluded that programming this yourself is not a good idea. The API is sufficiently broken - in my opinion - that it should not be implemented at all. I'm over 1 page of remarks already, and most of them are rather critical. I'll try and draw some attention to the API from people that matter. Please use Bouncy on SE.

Comment: ONe and a half pages, 23 bugs/remarks and counting... Ugh.

Comment: Programming is hard, but if completed, it is very happy, right?
I also try my best.

Comment: Bad API's are never happy. I'm happy when creating a very complex implementation so that's alright :)